# Set Android View color via XML which follows device theme (dark/light)

Tags: android, xml, colors, themes

I would like to use nativa Android color value which follows the device theme.

For example: I'm setting dark as color:

`android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"`

I'm trying to find out how to set something like this:

`android:textColor="@android:color/device_color_scheme_primary_text"`

Answer (score 1):

The best and most straightforward way is to create color attributes in your app. First, you need to Define the colors for the specific theme in your colors file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="my_link_color1">#0077CC</color>
    <color name="my_link_color2">#626262</color>
</resources>
```

Then create file res/values/attrs.xml with contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="myLinkColor" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

Suppose we have 2 themes in our styles.xml (Dark and Light) define:

```
<style name="Theme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="myLinkColor">@color/my_link_color1</item>
</style>
 
<style name="Theme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="myLinkColor">@color/my_link_color2</item>
</style>
```

And finally, use the color in the XML:

```
android:textColor="?attr/myLinkColor"
```

It also works if you define the same color name in different files one in `res/values/colors` and the other in `res/values-night/colors` in case you don't want to create different themes. This is easier than the previous solution.